# How to solve java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError for com.google.android.gms.R$styleable error?

Tags: android, google-maps, makefile, google-play-services, noclassdeffounderror

I use Google Maps in a project and build it with **Android.mk**. But still (after days of research) cann't figure out how to solve **NoClassDefFoundError** which crashes the apk in time Google Maps fragment inflation is happen. Can any inside me about a way it have to be solved? Detalization is below.

Google Play Services library is added in the following way:

```
#Adding classpath to Google Play Services classes
LOCAL_CLASSPATH += $(LOCAL_PATH)/google-play-services_lib/bin/
...
#Google Play Services
LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES += google-play-services \
                                google-play-services_lib
...
LOCAL_PREBUILT_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES += google-play-services:libs/google-play-services.jar \
                                        google-play-services_lib:libs/google-play-services_lib.jar
```

Build goes fine but application throws runtime error when tries to inflate layout with Google Maps fragment. **LogCat**:

```
**java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError**:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$styleable
    at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMapOptions.createFromAttributes(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
    at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4996)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:695)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
    at com.mapsvisitor.ui.MapsFragment.onCreateView(MapsFragment.java:81)
    ...
```

**Code**:

```
final View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.maps_layout, null);
```

**Layout**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Looks like you haven't referenced google play services properly

Comment: It looks so. But Google Play Services utils returns **True** for `isGooglePlayServicesAvailable` query. Have you any ideas how to references it within makefile?

Comment: Can you check properly if you have referenced google play services. Your device might have google play servicesa apk installed but have you referenced the same in your project??

Comment: Google play services version is correct (4452000). It's registered in manifest `<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
           android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />`. The problem with outdated services is happen before when `isGooglePlayServicesAvailable` has returned `ConnectionResult.SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED` (I have solved it earlier here: [How to update Google Play Services through adb?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24606574/how-to-update-google-play-services-through-adb)).

Comment: that is the only reason i can think of as of now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in that when you use dependency project as a library the generated JAR (google-play-services_lib.jar) is not suitable for independent use (as java static libraries). As solution simple use JAR generated by Eclipse export instead in the following way **Export > Java > JAR file** with selected **src** and **gen** folders to export:
[image]

The following snippet helps to define that **com.google.android.gms.R** and nested classes are unavailable (com.google.android.gms.R$attr, com.google.android.gms.R$color, etc):

```
void isClassesAvailable(List<String> classes) {
    for(String cl: classes) {
        try {
            Class.forName(cl);
        }
            catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            Log.w(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

How JAR is packed for dependency project (with src folder classes. See folder "android" below):
[image]

How JAR has to be packed for robust static library (with src and gen folder classes. See folders "android" and "com" below):
[image]

However before idiomatically right solution which uses Eclipse export light hack becomes the GTD. Simple **repacking google-play-services_lib.jar with google-play-services_lib/bin/classes** content and previously presented there ones makes all resource's classes available.